# Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - cat

Tags: ruby, shell, out-of-memory, fork, spawn

I have a job running on production which process xml files.
xml files counts around 4k and of size 8 to 9 GB all together.

After processing we get CSV files as output. I've a cat command which will merge all CSV files to a single file I'm getting:

> Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory

on `cat` (Backtick) command.

Below are few details:

- System Memory - 4 GB
- Swap - 2 GB
- Ruby : 1.9.3p286

Files are processed using `nokogiri` and `saxbuilder-0.0.8`.

Here, there is a block of code which will process 4,000 XML files and output is saved in CSV (1 per xml) (sorry, I'm not suppose to share it b'coz of company policy).

Below is the code which will merge the output files to a single file

```
Dir["#{processing_directory}/*.csv"].sort_by {|file| [file.count("/"), file]}.each {|file|
            `cat #{file} >> #{final_output_file}`
}
```

I've taken memory consumption snapshots during processing.It consumes almost all part of the memory, but, it won't fail.
It always fails on `cat` command.

I guess, on backtick it tries to fork a new process which doesn't get enough memory so it fails.

Please let me know your opinion and alternative to this.

Comment: IMO it'd make sense to actually show what you're doing.

Comment: You might be very low on memory for this to happen, are you sure you have enough memory left ? What's the output of ``free -m`` ?

Comment: @Intrepidd, I agree with you, free -m shows hardly 150 MB left out after processing around 3,000 files. But, it continues processing all files and only fails on cat command.

Comment: This is normal, you have enough memory for listing all the files and spawning a shell, but the spawned shell will fail when running cat, I'll write a solution for you and post it as an answer

Comment: @Intrepidd, That would be a great help, thank you :)

Comment: Refer to the following question and take a look at the accepted answer. It is a great explanation on what actually happen. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286002/ruby-cannot-allocate-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that your system is running pretty low on memory and spawning a shell + calling cat is too much for the few memory left.

If you don't mind loosing some speed, you can merge the files in ruby, with small buffers.
This avoids spawning a shell, and you can control the buffer size.

This is untested but you get the idea :

```
buffer_size = 4096
output_file = File.open(final_output_file, 'w')

Dir["#{processing_directory}/*.csv"].sort_by {|file| [file.count("/"), file]}.each do |file|
  f = File.open(file)
  while buffer = f.read(buffer_size)
    output_file.write(buffer)
  end
  f.close
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this might work, I'll try this and let you know. And, do you know any issues of Nokogiri on Ruby 1.9.3 related to memory?. We recently upgraded ruby from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3, I've a feeling that this might be a reason too.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably out of physical memory, so double check that and verify your swap (`free -m`). In case you don't have a swap space, [create one](https://askubuntu.com/a/796997/78223).

Otherwise if your memory is fine, the error is most likely caused by shell resource limits. You may check them by `ulimit -a`.

They can be changed by `ulimit` which can modify shell resource limits (see: `help ulimit`), e.g.

```
ulimit -Sn unlimited && ulimit -Sl unlimited
```

To make these limit persistent, you can configure it by creating the ulimit setting file by the following shell command:

```
cat | sudo tee /etc/security/limits.d/01-${USER}.conf <<EOF
${USER} soft core unlimited
${USER} soft fsize unlimited
${USER} soft nofile 4096
${USER} soft nproc 30654
EOF
```

---

Or use `/etc/sysctl.conf` to change the limit globally (`man sysctl.conf`), e.g.

```
kern.maxprocperuid=1000
kern.maxproc=2000
kern.maxfilesperproc=20000
kern.maxfiles=50000
```

Comment: That sounded plausible but I'm not seeing it present with ENOMEM, which is 12, 11 being EAGAIN:
    martind@pizzagate:~$ ruby -we 'Process.setrlimit(:NOFILE, 1); `true`'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     1: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    -e:1:in ``': Too many open files - true (Errno::EMFILE)
    martind@pizzagate:~$ ruby1.9.1 -we 'Process.setrlimit(:NPROC, 7); `true`'
    [FATAL] Failed to create timer thread (errno: 11)
    martind@pizzagate:~$

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but instead of `cat` it was `sendmail` (`gem mail`).

I found problem & solution [here](http://adamniedzielski.github.io/blog/2014/02/05/fighting-paperclip-errno-enomem-error/) by installing `posix-spawn` gem, e.g.

```
gem install posix-spawn
```

and here is the example:

```
a = (1..500_000_000).to_a

require 'posix/spawn'
POSIX::Spawn::spawn('ls')
```

> This time creating child process should succeed.

See also: [Minimizing Memory Usage for Creating Application Subprocesses](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/subprocess-136439.html) at Oracle.